# Виджет рейтинга от яндекса

Tags: виджет

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы виджет был не обрезан?

Или есть может похожий похожий?

https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/1181475989?type=alt&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Виджет не обрезан. Такова дизайнерская задумка Яндекса.
Если вам не нравится текущий, можете выбрать один из нескольких разного размера и типа. Можете глянуть на [сборной страничке](https://jsbin.com/hixujij/edit?html,output) или взять пример другого бейджа ниже:

```html
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/51090921020" width="150" height="50" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```